# Counting elements greater than a number in vector

Tags: c++, vector, stdvector, counting, c++03

I want to count the number of elements greater than a number in a c++ vector. The threshold value is to be taken input from the user.

The code for counting elements greater than a number is given as:

`ctr=count_if(v.begin(),v.end(), greater1);`

The corresponding function:

```
bool greater1(int value)
{
   return value >= 8;
}
```

The problem is I would know the threshold value(here 8) only before the `count_if` function call so I need to pass the threshold `t` as a parameter. How to establish the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like [NathanOliver said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57152051/27678), we need to "capture" the threshold value to be used internally. A lambda accomplishes that, but how?

When you write a lambda like

```
int threshold = 8;
std::count_if(/*...*/, [threshold](int next_val){return next_val >= threshold;});
```

In C++11 and beyond, the compiler uses this lambda syntax to generate a lightweight class that exposes the function call operator like so:

```
struct my_greater_equal
{
   explicit my_greater_equal(int _threshold) : threshold(_threshold){}
   bool operator()(int next_val) const
   {
      return next_val >= threshold;
   }
   int threshold;
};
```

(This is only *mostly* like what a lambda looks like)

Then an instance is created and used in `count_if` as-if:

```
std::count_if(my_collection.cbegin(), my_collection.cend(), my_greater_equal{8});
```

Internally, `std::count_if` calls `my_greater_equal::operator()` for each element in your collection.

Pre-C++11 we had to manually create these lightweight *function objects* (sometimes called *functors* even if that's not technically correct)

[C++03 Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/WG6RMoSBBciEP7Gi)

Things are much easier now :-)

Comment: I tried the code but I got error as `[Error] C:\Users\User\Documents\cp\Untitled2.cpp:33: error: expected primary-expression before '[' token` in the line `std::count_if(v1.begin(),v1.end(), [threshold](int next_val){return next_val >= threshold;});` I don't get what they want to say?

Comment: @Excelsior: What compiler are you using and what standard of C++ is it using?

Comment: g++ compiler and c++ version <c++11

Comment: @Excelsior: If the version is less than C++11, you cannot use lambdas. You must use the function object approach I outline above.

Comment: yes you are right, instead of lambda I used your function object approach and I got the error `[Error] C:\Users\User\Documents\cp\Untitled2.cpp:44: error: expected primary-expression before '{' token` in the line `std::count_if(v1.begin(), v1.end(), my_greater_equal{k+1});` . I wrote almost the same code before posting this question and got the same error.

Comment: @Excelsior: See the code in the demo link. Use `my_greater_equal(k+1)` instead of `my_greater_equal{k+1}`. The latter syntax is C++11

Comment: yes I just tried it intuitively and it worked. Oh silly me!! Thanks

Comment: np, glad it helped.

Answer (score 9):

**N.B. Only for c++11 standard**

The easiest way to do this is to use a [lambda expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda).  Using that you can build a functor (called a Closure Object) in the call site of `count_if` and you can use what you known then inside the body of the lambda.  That would leave you with something like

```
auto minimum_value = /* something that gets the minimum value you want to use for the comparison */
auto count = std::count_if(v.begin(), v.end(),[&](auto const& val){ return val >= minimum_value; });
//                                             ^ use this to capture a reference of minimum_value
```

Comment: Whether you have the lambda capture by value or by reference doesn't really matter for basic integer types. Typically you should capture by value

Comment: when I try to run the code I get the error `[Error] C:\Users\User\Documents\cp\Untitled2.cpp:37: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of `minimum_value' with no type` in the line `auto minimum_value = k+1`. I can't figure out why?Maybe because of C++ version incompatibility or compiler incompatibility?

Answer (score 3):

Make a function that gives you the threshold function!

```
auto above(int threshold) {
    // This captures a copy of threshold
    return [=](int value) {
        return value >= threshold;
    };
};
```

You can then get the count using `above`, just by passing the threshold as an argument:

```
auto count = count_if(v.begin(), v.end(), above(8));
```